# Can PHP offer accurate sent mail reports?

Tags: php, email

I´m using Drupal (PHP) and sometimes I use it to send email to some of my registered users (ie. using a contact form located inside their profile). This is very common in every CMS, PHP forum, etc.

The thing is that Drupal usually prints out a successful message when the email was sent, and not always the email is actually sent.

On the other hand, my hosting uses [VHM](https://cpanel.net/) panel with VPS servers.
From their control panel I can check all mail that goes from my server to the outside. In VHM it´s called "Mail Delivery Reports". That´s accurate enough, and I think most VPS control panel probably have some similar utility.

My question is: When Drupal tells me that the email has been sent, and I go to the Mail Delivery report on my hosting control panel, and it says that it has not been sent. **Is that a PHP flaw?
Is there a way to get accurate reports within PHP?**

Please excuse my grammar. It has been kinda difficult for me to actually get myself clear on what I mean in english.

### UPDATE:

I´m not asking if the user reads the email, not even if it later on gets bounced, just to know if PHP has some accurate way to report if the email was sent.

I know there are some services offering that, but **I´m just asking about PHP capabilities (and if that´s actually possible)**.

Comment: left mail server and delivered are not the same thing NOTHING can tell you with any accuracy if a user actully saw the email.

Comment: In work we use sendgrid to send our emails, it features a "open report", but that still isn't 100% accurate.

Comment: Mandrill is pretty good for this type of thing

Comment: 'open reports' are not much more than a marketing joke, they are so meaningless.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I´m not asking is the user saw the email. I´m asking for an accurate way to know that the email was actually SENT from my server. It can even get bounced later on, but how may I accurate know if it was SENT?

Comment: check the mail server logs. you can do that with php if you like

Comment: You're asking a server related question which you have nailed the essence of it at `accurate way to know that the email was actually SENT from my server.`, can PHP be responsible? Yes it can in several ways for example broken or poor coding, your server resources being fully used causing your PHP to stop mid way and others, but if the command is sent to your mail server, essentially it will depend 100% on the System Administrator and server weather or not it will have a high delivery rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is impossible for PHP to track sent emails. That is not, never has been, and never will be, PHP's job.

PHP simply generates the email (e.g. builds the html) and then hands it over to a mail transfer agent. e.g. your local sendmail.

In a real-world equivalent, PHP is you walking an envelope down to the street corner and dropping it into the mailbox. If the letter disappears down the chute, PHP will report success. After that, actual DELIVERY of the mail is entirely out of PHP's hands.

Maybe the mailbox gets flattened by a drunk driver, maybe the pickup truck gets into a firey crash, maybe the postal sorting facility gets hit by a meteor, etc...

None of that is PHP's problem, and undetectable by PHP anyways. It walked down the street, it saw the letter disappear down the slots. Mission accomplished.

At best you could set the "return service requested" mail headers, which 99.99% of people will probably ignore or disallow, or embed a web-bug inside the email and hope that the recipient's mail client will actually load the bug.

Answer (score 5):

PHP responsibility is to give it to your specified transport method. (sendmail, smtp etc.) and tell you if the transport accepted it or not.

If you use sendmail (or postfix) what php tells you is that it has been queued for sending and nothing else. PHP doesn't know if it will be sent or not. unless you parse the queues and try to go from there.